# Помогите разобратся с отправкой формы в БД на WordPress (аналог добавления записи из админки)

Tags: php, wordpress

Отправка формы трех полей в базу данных: post_name, slug, post_content, но что-то не пойму, как осуществляется отправка данных. Почитал, как в wordpress отправляются данные в бд, но что-то ничего не отправляется...Суть должна быть, примерно как отправка записи через админку (титулка, рубрика, текст)
functions.php:

```
function theme_form_init() {

    if( ! isset($_POST['submit']) ) return false;

    global $wpdb;

    $args = array(
        'post_name'     => isset($_POST['post_name']) ? esc_attr( trim($_POST['post_name']) ) : '',
        'slug'          => isset($_POST['slug']) ? esc_attr( trim($_POST['slug']) ) : '',
        'post_content'  => isset($_POST['post_content']) ? esc_attr( trim($_POST['post_content']) ) : ''
    );

}
add_action('wp', 'theme_form_init');
}
```